# Как последовательно сложить число с каждым элементом списка?

Tags: python

```
from random import randint
count = int( input ( 'Введите количетсво элементов массива: ' ) )
a = []
for i in range( count  ):
    a.append( randint(0, 5) )#крч тут заполнил список
print('Список: ', a )
for i in range(count - 1):
    if a[i] == a[i + range(1, count)]:
        print('Да, есть одинаковые числа',a[i])
    else:
        print('Одинаковых чисел нет(((')
```

Вот заполнен список. Должен работать он так: если первый элемент (i) равен либо 2 элементу(i+1) либо 3 элементу(i+2) ...и так далее, пока список не закончится. Только вот нельзя складывать число и  функцию range(). Что делать?

Можно бы что-то типо этого, но опять ошибка:

```
from random import randint
count = int( input ( 'Введите количетсво элементов массива: ' ) )
a = []
for i in range( count  ):
    a.append( randint(0, 5) )#крч тут заполнил список
print('Список: ', a )
for i in range(count - 1):
    if a[i] == a[i + g for g in range(1,count)]:
        print('Да, есть одинаковые числа',a[i])
    else:
        print('Одинаковых чисел нет(((')
```

Comment: попробуйте заменить `if a[i] == a[i + range(1, count)]:` на `if a[i] in a[i+1:]:`

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
from random import randint

count = int(input('Введите количетсво элементов массива: '))
a = []

for i in range(count):
    a.append(randint(0, 5))                     #крч тут заполнил список

print('Список: ', a )

for i in range(count - 1):
#    if a[i] == a[i + range(1, count)]:
    if a[i] in a[i+1:]:
        print('Да, есть одинаковые числа', a[i], i)
    else:
        print('Одинаковых чисел нет(((')
```